# CI3 - Count and Joins in Active Record

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I just can't get this working.  I have a table called categories like this:

```
table name:  categories
id
name
```

and a posts table like this:

```
table name: posts
id
category_id
title
body
```

I am writing a controller/model/view to list the category.name and the number of posts belonging to the at category.  I am crashing and burning how to do this.  This a partial attempt.

```
$this->db->select('
                posts.*,
                categories.*,
                COUNT(posts.category_id) as num_posts
            ');
$this->db->from('posts');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = posts.category_id');
$xx = $this->db->get();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($xx);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit();
```

Any help very much appreciated.  Have searched my of stackoverflow but can't see a CI3 solution.

new update.  This sql works:

```
SELECT
    categories.id,
    categories.name,
    Count(posts.id) as cnt
FROM
    categories
LEFT JOIN
    posts
ON
    categories.id=posts.category_id
GROUP BY
    categories.name
```

When I run it I get below which is what I expected:

```
id     name                              cnt
---------------------------------------------
80  |  24354234234                    |  2
76  |  Associations and Organizations |  9
```

But when I change to active record like this:

```
$this->db->select('categories.id, categories.name, COUNT(posts.id) as num_posts');
$this->db->from('categories');
$this->db->join('posts', 'categories.id = posts.category_id');
$this->db->group_by('categories.name');
$xx = $this->db->get();
```

I print_r($xx) and don't see any of my data.  This is what I get:

```
CI_DB_mysqli_result Object
(
[conn_id] => mysqli Object
    (
        [affected_rows] => 2
        [client_info] => 5.5.59
        [client_version] => 50559
        [connect_errno] => 0
        [connect_error] => 
        [errno] => 0
        [error] => 
        [error_list] => Array
            (
            )

        [field_count] => 3
        [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket
        [info] => 
        [insert_id] => 0
        [server_info] => 5.5.58-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
        [server_version] => 50558
        [stat] => Uptime: 7546485  Threads: 2  Questions: 523149  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 257  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 200  Queries per second avg: 0.069
        [sqlstate] => 00000
        [protocol_version] => 10
        [thread_id] => 42310
        [warning_count] => 0
    )

[result_id] => mysqli_result Object
    (
        [current_field] => 0
        [field_count] => 3
        [lengths] => 
        [num_rows] => 2
        [type] => 0
    )

[result_array] => Array
    (
    )

[result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[custom_result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[current_row] => 0
[num_rows] => 
[row_data] => 
)
```

Still don't know how to get an array.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: how about `$this->db->select('categories.*,COUNT(posts.posts.id) as num_posts');` ?

Comment: Thanks.  It gives and error.  Error Number: 1051

Unknown table 'categories'

SELECT `categories`.*, COUNT(posts.posts.id) as num_posts

Filename: models/Blog_model.php

Line Number: 68

Comment: yeah ok - now think about it - what does that mean ? ;)

Comment: Thank you.  I can see that the result object may have the data?  3 fields and 2 rows.  

[result_id] => mysqli_result Object
    (
        [current_field] => 0
        [field_count] => 3
        [lengths] => 
        [num_rows] => 2
        [type] => 0
    )

Comment: How would I access that?

Comment: `$this->db->join('posts', 'categories.id = posts.category_id', 'left');` you forgot the _left_ in your join clause.

Answer (score 0):

I found this which explains why the values were blank:  [Codeigniter query returning blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194706/codeigniter-query-returning-blank)

Further documentation is here.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Therefore, this would echo the values:

```
... extension of previous code
$xx = $this->db->get();
print_r($xx->result_array());
```